# How to revert insert statement in postgres table without timestamp column

Tags: postgresql

I wrote and executed a springboot application to run batch inserts in postgres table having no timestamp column. Now I realised those inserts were not desired and since they were done on a production database, I seek some way to delete those rows altogether. Is there any way to do so, especially when there is no timestamp column. Does postgres internally save any such time related information for state changing operations? Any help is appreciated.

Tried looking for time related data in Dbeaver but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql does not store timestamp of insertion on records..
Many of us use triggers or columns with a default value of now() or something to help with these issues-- but that won't help you now, it's just for future reference.